# Import error while launching PyTorch Lightning project on Colab TPU

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pytorch-lightning, tensorflow-xla

I followed this [guide](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/tpu.html#colab-tpus) to launch my PyTorch Lightning project on Google Colab TPU. So I installed

```
!pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/torch_xla-1.9-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Then

```
 !pip install pytorch-lightning
```

Then I

```
!pip install torch torchvision torchaudio 
!pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After installing the project requirements, I restarted the runtime as requested and re-ran the cloud-TPU-client install, the pytorch-lightning install, and both command from above. It ran smoothly.

But just after the TPU has started with version PyTorch version 1.9, I get the following import error :

```
WARNING:root:TPU has started up successfully with version pytorch-1.9
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "synthesizer_train.py", line 2, in <module>
            from synthesizer.train import train
          File "/content/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning/synthesizer/train.py", line 6, in <module>
            from synthesizer.models.tacotron import Tacotron
          File "/content/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning/synthesizer/models/tacotron.py", line 7, in <module>
            import pytorch_lightning as pl
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
            from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import Callback  # noqa: E402
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
            from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.base import Callback
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/base.py", line 26, in <module>
            from pytorch_lightning.utilities.types import STEP_OUTPUT
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
            from pytorch_lightning.utilities.apply_func import move_data_to_device  # noqa: F401
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/apply_func.py", line 26, in <module>
            from pytorch_lightning.utilities.imports import _compare_version, _TORCHTEXT_AVAILABLE
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/imports.py", line 101, in <module>
            from pytorch_lightning.utilities.xla_device import XLADeviceUtils  # noqa: E402
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/xla_device.py", line 24, in <module>
            import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch_xla/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
            import _XLAC
        ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/_XLAC.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2at13_foreach_erf_EN3c108ArrayRefINS_6TensorEEE
```

`Trainer` was launched with the flag `TPU_cores=8`.

The model had run on CPU and GPU beforehand (ie on another session).

I tried to downgrade PyTorch to 1.9 (the same as the one shown when TPU is starting) because Colab uses torch 1.10.0+cu111 and a different error appeared :

```
WARNING:root:TPU has started up successfully with version pytorch-1.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "synthesizer_train.py", line 2, in <module>
    from synthesizer.train import train
  File "/content/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning/synthesizer/train.py", line 6, in <module>
    from synthesizer.models.tacotron import Tacotron
  File "/content/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning/synthesizer/models/tacotron.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pytorch_lightning as pl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import Callback  # noqa: E402
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.base import Callback
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/base.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.utilities.types import STEP_OUTPUT
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pytorch_lightning.utilities.apply_func import move_data_to_device  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/apply_func.py", line 29, in <module>
    if _compare_version("torchtext", operator.ge, "0.9.0"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/imports.py", line 54, in _compare_version
    pkg = importlib.import_module(package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchtext/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import vocab
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchtext/vocab/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .vocab_factory import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchtext/vocab/vocab_factory.py", line 4, in <module>
    from torchtext._torchtext import (
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchtext/_torchtext.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN5torch3jit6MethodE
```

Is there anything I can do to train the model on TPU ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Actually the same problem has also been described and the [suggested solution](https://github.com/pytorch/xla/issues/3215#issuecomment-970297237) did work for me.

So in the details they suggest to downgrade PyTorch to `1.9.0+cu111` (mind the `+cu111`) after installing torch_xla.

Consequently here are the steps I followed to launch my Lightning project on Google Colab with TPU :

```
!pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/torch_xla-1.9-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
!pip install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchtext==0.10.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html
```

And then the project's pip :

```
!pip install torch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-lightning
!pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And it worked even though after this last step, I had to restart runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Based on above solution, we could additionally fix the issue for sure by finding the version of cuda installed with

```
import torch
torch.version.cuda

10.2
```

Based on this cuda version perform this `pip install` command

```
!pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 torchvision==0.12.0+cu102 torch==1.11.0+cu102 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/colab/torch_xla-1.11-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch_stable.html
```

Pls notice the `cu102` in three places in the above command